# Not able to add Image on the top center of the resume between written texts

Tags: graphics, horizontal-alignment

Pardon my English, Can someone please help me to add an image at the center, between the name and the email. Here is the code I've been using.

```
\begin{document}

%----------HEADING-----------------

\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}

  \textbf{{\LARGE Sarvesh Patil}} & Email: \href{mailto:}{sarveshpatilxx2001@gmail.com}\\ 
  
\href{https://www.linkedin.com/in/patil-sarvesh/}{LinkedIn: linkedin.com/in/patil-sarvesh} & Mobile:~~~+9192227922xx \\
  
\href{https://github.com/Patil-Sarvesh}{Github: ~~github.com/Patil-Sarvesh} \\
\end{tabular*}
```

[image: The image is from Overleaf where I wanted to create my resume. And add an image at the center, between the name and the email.]

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

[image]

```
\usepackage[margin=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{hyperref}


\begin{document}
\noindent\begin{tblr}{colspec ={X[l] c X[l]}}
\LARGE \textbf{Sarvesh Patil}
    & \SetCell[r=2]{h}  \includegraphics[width=21mm, valign=t]{example-image-duck}
        &    \SetCell[r=2]{h}   {Email: \href{mailto:}{sarveshpatilxx2001@gmail.com}\\
                                 Mobile:  +9192227922xx}        \\ 
{\href{https://www.linkedin.com/in/patil-sarvesh/}{LinkedIn: linkedin.com/in/patil-sarvesh} \\
 \href{https://github.com/Patil-Sarvesh}{Github: github.com/Patil-Sarvesh}}
    &   &                               \\
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```